# velocity template and javascript

Tags: java, spring-mvc, velocity

I try add javascript to my velocity template.

```
<html>

<head>
<title>:: $currency.CurrencyName Detail Info ::</title>
</head>

<body>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>$currency.CurrencyName</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Jual</td>
  <td><div id="$currency.CurrencyName_buy">$currency.Buy</div></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Beli</td>
  <td><div id="$currency.CurrencyName_sell">$currency.Sell</div></td>
 </tr>
</table>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            $.get('updateCurrency.htm', function(data) {
                $('#time').text(data);         
            });
        }, 5 * 60 * 1000); // 1000 milliseconds = 1 second.
    });
</script>

<p>Current date/time is: <span id="time"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

but I got the following error:

```
org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered "," at line 28, column 29 of currencyDetail.html
Was expecting one of:
    <EOF> 
    "(" ...
    <RPAREN> ...
    <ESCAPE_DIRECTIVE> ...
    <SET_DIRECTIVE> ...
    "##" ...
    "\\\\" ...
    "\\" ...
    <TEXT> ...
    "*#" ...
    "*#" ...
    <STRING_LITERAL> ...
    <IF_DIRECTIVE> ...
    <STOP_DIRECTIVE> ...
    <INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
    <FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ...
    <WORD> ...
    <BRACKETED_WORD> ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    <DOT> ...
    "{" ...
    "}" ...

 at org.apache.velocity.Template.process(Template.java:137)
 at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.loadResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:415)
 at org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.getResource(ResourceManagerImpl.java:335)
 at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1102)
 at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.getTemplate(RuntimeInstance.java:1077)
 at org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.getTemplate(VelocityEngine.java:528)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityView.getTemplate(VelocityView.java:535)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityView.getTemplate(VelocityView.java:520)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityView.checkTemplate(VelocityView.java:293)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityView.initApplicationContext(VelocityView.java:258)
 at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:73)
 at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:70)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:323)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:314)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.loadView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:413)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.createView(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:159)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver.createView(UrlBasedViewResolver.java:378)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.resolveViewName(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:78)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherServlet.java:1190)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1139)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:808)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:476)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:431)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.parsePage(PageFilter.java:119)
 at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:55)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

If I remove the javascript script, the web page loaded succesfully. any one can explain why ? I think javascript doesn't work if using velocity template.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In Velocity 1.7b1 new syntax `#[[this is included in output but not parsed]]#` was introduced:

```
#[[
    $(document).ready(function() {
        ...
    });
]]#
```

Answer (score 9):

When I mix jquery and Velocity, I find the simplest thing to do is to use "jQuery" instead of $, e.g.

```
jQuery("#divid")
```

This avoids any difficulties -- escaping in velocity is tricky and non-intuitive.

Answer (score 6):

Another way is to add javscript to its own file, and use the #include vtl script directive.

E.g.:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
     #include( "currencyDetail.js")
</script>
```

contents of currencyDetail.js (located in same dir / classpath package as .vm file):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.get('updateCurrency.htm', function(data) {
            $('#time').text(data);         
        });
    }, 5 * 60 * 1000); // 1000 milliseconds = 1 second.
});
```

This was easiest for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have Velocity 1.7+ or need to use Velocity code as part of the javascript or jquery you can identify the key words in the javascript/jquery that are causing a problem and put them in a variable. Velocity will then render the output correctly.

First set the variable:

```
#set ( $replaceme = "each" )
```

Then use it in the code:

```
function reverseCommentOrder(){
  $comments = AJS.$('#page-comments');
  $comments.children().$replaceme(function(i,li){$comments.prepend(li)});
}
```

This results in javascript working on the page.