# How to include JavaScript file inside a Velocity template?

Tags: javascript, java, html, web, velocity

I have a JS file having contents:
`function rejectIfNotSuccess(response) {} usernameChanged(event) {}` for example, and I want to include this file in my velocity template in order to do things the same way we do in an HTML file.

For example, I want to call a function defined in this JS file in velocity using `<input type="text" id="username" onInput="javascript:usernameChanged(event)" />`

How can I do so?
I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7530746/13616209) about a way to do so, which may work. But, are there any other better ways of doing the same?

Thanks Stephen for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you do it that same way that you would do it if you were writing the HTML file by hand.  Embed an appropriate `<script>` element into the velocity template that generates that HTML.

(The `<script>` element could contain the function declaration, or it could use a `src` link to load a document containing the Javascript from your server.  See https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/javascript/script-tag for examples.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Stephen C . I'll try this out.